# How to store parameter store after login react native

Tags: reactjs, native

Making a small application in react native with using php API but after login need to store user id(fetching from database) for further use like profile edit... Etc how to do this

Comment: try this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use asyncstorage for such kind of things.

> import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native"

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you it works but when use multiset and multiget showing warning
"Array[[Error.java.lang.DOuble cannot be cast to java.lang.String],

Comment: AsyncStorage.multiSet([
          ["userId", responseJson.USERID],
          ["refcode", responseJson.SUCCESS]
      ])
=======================
 AsyncStorage.multiGet(['userId', 'refcode']).then((data) => {
        let userId = data[1];
        let refcode = data[1];
    
            
    });